# Should we write separate page-object for the error pop-ups coming in a page?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

Selenium Java Page-Object Model: Should we write separate page-object for the error pop-ups coming in a page?
I am using the Page Object model and have each page as a single class and the actions in that page as methods.
Now, Should i include the pop-up handling on the same page as a method or should I have to create a separate page-object class for those pop-ups?
What is the best practice.?
Each pop-up has 2 options and some info about the pop-up to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all pop-ups have particular properties in common, you can create a separate class which would be included into each Page Object. If those description and option fields are always identified with same locators, it seems like a great idea.

In case those pop-ups differ in a way it is hard to handle them with single class you might consider creating an interface for pop-ups and have each of actual Page Object implement it and handle it on its own.